# error[E0277]: the trait bound `MovieAccountState: borsh::de::BorshDeserialize` is not satisfied

Tags: rust, solana

I'm trying to follow the Solana tutorial for creating programs on chain, but I got stucked because I get this error:

```
    error[E0277]: the trait bound `MovieAccountState: borsh::de::BorshDeserialize` is not satisfied
  --> /src/lib.rs:80:26
   |
80 |   let mut account_data = try_from_slice_unchecked::<MovieAccountState>(&pda_account.data.borrow()).unwrap();
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `borsh::de::BorshDeserialize` is not implemented for `MovieAccountState`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `borsh::de::BorshDeserialize`:
```

Even tho I'm implementing the BorshDeserialize trait on the MoviceAccountState struct like this:

```
use borsh::{BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize};

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)]
pub struct MovieAccountState {
    pub is_initialized: bool,
    pub rating: u8,
    pub description: String,
    pub title: String
}
```

The error happens in this line of code:

```
let mut account_data = try_from_slice_unchecked::<MovieAccountState>(&pda_account.data.borrow()).unwrap();
```

The link of the tutorial is this: https://www.soldev.app/course/program-state-management

I tried to run the code solution as well but it gets the same error.

Comment: Please provide your dependencies and versions (and which dependency `try_from_slice_unchecked` is from). You may have an incompatibility.

Comment: I don't have the dependencies since I'm working from the Solana Playgorund, and try_from_slice_unchecked is coming from the solana crate:
use solana_program::{
    ...
    borsh::try_from_slice_unchecked,
};

Comment: Weird, but it confirms my suspicions: The Solana Playground [lists its dependencies](https://github.com/solana-playground/solana-playground) which includes `borsh` v0.10 but `solana_program` re-exports `borsh` v0.9. So if you mix the two you might run into problems. Try using just `borsh::try_from_slice_unchecked` instead of `solana_program::borsh::try_from_slice_unchecked`.

Comment: Oh nevermind, that method doesn't exist in the normal borsh crate, but its [not too hard to make it yourself](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/src/solana_program/borsh.rs.html#78-82).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error. Based on the comments to the original question i created my own `try_from_slice_unchecked` implementation, which wasn't ideal.
I was getting naming conflicts so just renamed it to `my_try_from_slice_unchecked`. The function looks like this:

```
pub fn my_try_from_slice_unchecked<T: borsh::BorshDeserialize>(data: &[u8]) -> Result<T, ProgramError> {
  let mut data_mut = data;
  match T::deserialize(&mut data_mut) {
    Ok(result) => Ok(result),
    Err(_) => Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)
  }
}
```

I also had to add `program_error::ProgramError,` to `use solana_program::{`

And replace `try_from_slice_unchecked` with `my_try_from_slice_unchecked`

So my final `lib.rs` file looked like this before it would build successfully:

```
use solana_program::{
  entrypoint,
  entrypoint::ProgramResult,
  pubkey::Pubkey,
  msg,
  account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
  system_instruction,
  sysvar::{rent::Rent, Sysvar},
  program::{invoke_signed},
  program_error::ProgramError,
};
use std::convert::TryInto;
pub mod instruction;
pub mod state;
use instruction::MovieInstruction;
use state::MovieAccountState;
use borsh::BorshSerialize;

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

pub fn my_try_from_slice_unchecked<T: borsh::BorshDeserialize>(data: &[u8]) -> Result<T, ProgramError> {
  let mut data_mut = data;
  match T::deserialize(&mut data_mut) {
    Ok(result) => Ok(result),
    Err(_) => Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)
  }
}

pub fn process_instruction(
  program_id: &Pubkey,
  accounts: &[AccountInfo],
  instruction_data: &[u8]
) -> ProgramResult {
  let instruction = MovieInstruction::unpack(instruction_data)?;
  match instruction {
    MovieInstruction::AddMovieReview { title, rating, description } => {         
      add_movie_review(program_id, accounts, title, rating, description)
    }
  }
}

pub fn add_movie_review(
  program_id: &Pubkey,
  accounts: &[AccountInfo],
  title: String,
  rating: u8,
  description: String
) -> ProgramResult {
  // Get Account iterator
  let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
  
  // Get accounts
  let initializer = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
  let pda_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
  let system_program = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
  
  let (pda, bump_seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[initializer.key.as_ref(), title.as_bytes().as_ref(),], program_id);

  // Calculate account size required
  let account_len: usize = 1 + 1 + (4 + title.len()) + (4 + description.len());
  
  // Calculate rent required
  let rent = Rent::get()?;
  let rent_lamports = rent.minimum_balance(account_len);

  // Create the account
  invoke_signed(
    &system_instruction::create_account(
      initializer.key,
      pda_account.key,
      rent_lamports,
      account_len.try_into().unwrap(),
      program_id,
    ),
    &[initializer.clone(), pda_account.clone(), system_program.clone()],
    &[&[initializer.key.as_ref(), title.as_bytes().as_ref(), &[bump_seed]]],
  )?;
    
  msg!("PDA created: {}", pda);

  msg!("unpacking state account");
  let mut account_data = my_try_from_slice_unchecked::<MovieAccountState>(&pda_account.data.borrow()).unwrap();
  msg!("borrowed account data");
  
  account_data.title = title;
  account_data.rating = rating;
  account_data.description = description;
  account_data.is_initialized = true;
  
  msg!("serializing account");
  account_data.serialize(&mut &mut pda_account.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;
  msg!("state account serialized");

  Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function solana_program::borsh0_9::try_from_slice_unchecked instead of solana_program::borsh::try_from_slice_unchecked to fix this error.